# ¿Cómo enviar esta petición con json en Guzzle?

Tags: php, laravel, http, guzzle, peticion

Primero agradecer a todos los que lean esta pregunta, resulta que yo manejaba javascript y utilizaba objetos json para manejar peticiones con el paquete de axios. Ahora, en mi trabajo usamos MVC en Laravel (PHP). Tengo que enviar una petición a una API y encontré el paquete Guzzle. No puedo usar axios porque tengo que crear un método en un controlador para hacer la petición en el backend.

Encontré la función json_encode y json_decode, funciona perfecto para convertir alguna clase o modelo en json o decodificar un json.

El problema es que en el cuerpo (body) de la petición HTTP (POST) tengo que enviar ciertos parámetros para esperar una respuesta correcta o incorrecta.

Ejecutando la petición en Postman, el body en json es el siguiente:

```
{
    "repactacion": {
    "usuarioInterfaz":"usuario",
    "passwordInterfaz":"SHA1",
    "rutAlumno":"18350123",
    "codigoCarrera":"0110XXXX",
    "codigoAlumno":"20191011033XXXX",
    "idCuotasRepactar":"7XXXXX",
    "Cuotas": [
         {
            "numeroCuota":"1",
            "monto":"105000",
            "fecha":"30-08-2021"
         }, 
         {
            "numeroCuota":"2",
            "monto":"105000",
            "fecha":"30-09-2021"
         }
        ]
    }
}
```

Tengo los siguientes modelos básicos

```
class Repactacion
{
    public $usuarioInterfaz = "";
    public $passwordInterfaz = "";
    public $rutAlumno = "";
    public $codigoCarrera = "";
    public $codigoAlumno = "";
    public $idCuotasRepactar = "";
    public $cuotas = [];
}

class Cuota {
    public $numeroCuota = 0;
    public $monto = 0;
    public $fecha = "";
}
```

Luego defino los valores de ejemplo, que en producción lo obtendré mediante un algoritmo interno.

```
$repactacion = new Repactacion();
$repactacion->usuarioInterfaz = "usuario";
$repactacion->passwordInterfaz = "SHA1";
$repactacion->rutAlumno = "16XXXXXX";
$repactacion->codigoCarrera = "011XXXXX";
$repactacion->codigoAlumno = "201910110XXXXXX";
$repactacion->idCuotasRepactar = "7XXXXX";
$cuota = new Cuota();
$cuota->numeroCuota = 1;
$cuota->monto = 200000;
$cuota->fecha = "23-06-2021";
$cuota2 = new Cuota();
$cuota2->numeroCuota = 2;
$cuota2->monto = 200000;
$cuota2->fecha = "23-07-2021";
array_push($repactacion->Cuotas, $cuota, $cuota2);
```

Sí aplico un json_encode obtengo lo siguiente:

```
json_encode($repactacion)
//Resultado
{
"usuarioInterfaz":"1066",
"passwordInterfaz":"6367c48dd193d56ea7b0baad25b19455e529f5ee",
"rutAlumno":"16546038",
"codigoCarrera":"01103305",
"codigoAlumno":"2019101103305015",
"idCuotasRepactar":"708928",
"Cuotas":[
    {
     "numeroCuota":1,
     "monto":200000,
     "fecha":"23-06-2021"
    },
    {
     "numeroCuota":2,
     "monto":200000,
     "fecha":"23-07-2021"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hasta aquí bien, esos son los datos que necesito enviar. Ahora necesito enviar la solicitud, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
client = new Client();
$body['repactacion'] = $repactacion;
$body = json_encode($body);
$URI_Response = $client->request('POST', $URI, ['body' => $body]);
$URI_Response = json_decode($URI_Response->getBody(), true);
return $URI_Response;
```

Al ejecutar el método Laravel arroja el siguiente resultado de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No estoy muy familiarizado con Guzzle y las peticiones HTTP con diferentes métodos. Buscando en Stackoverflow encontré esta manera de enviar una petición POST con un body en formato JSON pero, no logro obtener una respuesta en la petición.

En Postman, funciona correctamente la petición arrojando el código de estado 200.

De antemano, agradecería a las personas que conozcan esta librería pudiesen darme una mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que parece estar mal es que, en [peticiones POST](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#post-form-requests), debes enviar un arreglo y no un JSON. Revisa el ejemplo:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', [
    // Esto es un arreglo, no un JSON
    'form_params' => [
        'field_name' => 'abc',
        'other_field' => '123',
        'nested_field' => [
            'nested' => 'hello'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Con base en tu código, la petición debería ser más o menos así:

```
client = new Client();
$URI_Response = $client->request('POST', $URI, [
    'body' => ['repactacion' => $repactacion]
]);
```

En caso de tener que enviar como JSON, entonces hay que revisar [los ejemplos](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#uploading-data) para ver que solo se cambia `body` por `json`; supongo que Guzzle no solo enviará los encabezados correctos, sino que también hará lo necesario para formatear:

```
client = new Client();
$URI_Response = $client->request('POST', $URI, [
    'json' => ['repactacion' => $repactacion]
]);
```

Luego, en caso de errores, necesitas saber qué es lo que está pasando para saber qué es lo que debes corregir. De acuerdo a la [documentación oficial](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#exceptions) puedes capturar los errores HTTP:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

try {
    client = new Client();
    $URI_Response = $client->request('POST', $URI, [
        'body' => ['repactacion' => $repactacion]
    ]);
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    echo Psr7\Message::toString($e->getRequest());
    if ($e->hasResponse()) {
        echo Psr7\Message::toString($e->getResponse());
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso resuelve mi problema no conocía ese detalle. De todas maneras, indagando en stackoverflow encontre que Laravel incluye una libreria para peticiones HTTP, así que utilice esta herramienta y funciono perfecto.